# Finding a current source in a conductive plane

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I recently learned about RF direction-finding techniques using antenna arrays, and it got me thinking about whether it would be possible to locate an electrical signal source on a large conductive plane. Imagine a thin sheet of metal around 2m x 2m with a signal source and sink at opposing corners. If you put very precise voltmeter probes across the middle, would you "see" the signal at slightly different time offsets and be able to determine the direction of the source? I initially imagined the signal moving in an expanding circle from the source, but I guess the signal strength would be strongest in the straight line between the terminals and follow arcs of decreasing intensity outward (due to increasing impedance)? Are there other propagation effects I'm not thinking about?

I realize there are practical issues with measuring the signal with sufficient precision - this is just a thought experiment.

Comment: Do you need to do this at RF, or would a DC measurement be okay?

Comment: @ThePhoton DC only

Comment: On a sheet with uniform resistance, measuring the voltage at the 4 corners will suffice to locate to source of a current. This was (still is?) used for position sensitive detection of photons, using a microchannel plate to generate and amplify an electron pulse from a single photon. Quite useful back in the day before good quality CCDs were available.